Partial View .Net MVC render javascript file
I have an error when loading a partial view in the following way, the problem is that when loading a second time the modal window tries to load the javascript file, therefore it gives an error in the variables that have already been declared more than once.
Partial View Controller
  [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult _ClaimDetail()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }

Javascript call to load modal
$(buttonCharge).ModalPersonalize('show', urlController, 'rebuild title');
PartialView Modal cshtml
<div class="modalbody">

</div>
<div class="modalbuttons">

</div>
</div>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/JavacriptLogicModal.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

The error occurs when the modal is opened for the second time, How could I solve it, some way to render once the javascript file?
I already tried adding validations but nothing works

Don't pollute the global namespace. Use a JavaScript function.

To resolve the issue of JavaScript errors when reopening the modal window due to the script being loaded multiple times, you can follow one of these approaches:
1. Load the JavaScript Once in the Layout
Instead of loading the script within the partial view, you can include it in the main layout file or the specific view that initially calls the modal. This ensures that the script is only loaded once and is available throughout the lifecycle of your page.
 <!-- In your layout or main view --> <script src="@Url.Content("~/JavascriptLogicModal.js")" type="text/javascript"</script>

2. Check if the Script is Already Loaded
You can add a check before loading the script to see if it has already been loaded. This prevents the script from being loaded multiple times.
if (typeof YourVariableOrFunctionName === 'undefined') {
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = '@Url.Content("~/JavascriptLogicModal.js")';
document.head.appendChild(script);}


Re: "Load the JavaScript Once in the Layout " - I doubt the OP wants the <script> imported into every page - so you should expand your example to show how the _Layout.cshtml will only include scripts added at the direction of a Partial View.

Re: "Check if the Script is Already Loaded" - this approach only works for dynamically-added <script> elements and when the .js file makes use of var globals, which are a rarity in modern JS - and won't work at all with modules.
